# What is the syntax for adding multiple arguments onto the "Variables" parameter in sqlpackage.exe?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, database-deployment

I am using `SqlPackage.exe` for my deployment.  I have read the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) for the usage of `SqlPackage.exe`.

The documentation only states the synax for one variable:

> Specifies a name value pair for an action specific variable; {VariableName}={Value}. The DACPAC file contains the list of valid SQLCMD variables. An error will result if a value is not provided for every variable.

My problem is that the documentation does not say how to pass multiple arguments into the `Variables` parameter.  For example, I want to do this:

```
sqlpackage.exe ...args go here...  /Variables:VarToOverride=Value1,Var2ToOverride=Value2
```

Does anyone know the syntax for this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have managed to find something that works.

`sqlpackage.exe ...args go here... /Variables:VarToOverride=Value1 /Variables:Var2ToOverride=Value2`

It's not exactly what I was looking for, but it works.

Comment: Does anyone else feel it is odd that a flat to be used for a single variable is written in the plural? `/Variable:Foo=Bar` would have made more sense.

Comment: This worked for me, and `/v:var1=val1 /v:var2=val2 /v:var3=val3` also works `/v: is a shortcut for /variables:`

Answer (score 2):

Did you try separating using semi-colons rather than commas. i.e.:

```
sqlpackage.exe ...args go here...  /Variables:VarToOverride=Value1;Var2ToOverride=Value2
```

Your other option is to use Publish Profile files.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the multiple arguments as below.
/p:CreateNewDatabase=True /p:Storage=File /p:DatabaseEdition=Standard /p:DatabaseServiceObjective=S3 /p:DatabaseMaximumSize=50
Giving space after each argument.