# How to use multiple SQLCMD variables with SqlPackage.exe while deploying a DacPac?

Tags: sqlcmd, sqlpackage

I am deploying a dacpac using sqlpackage.exe and need to pass SqlCMD variables for a postdeployment script in the dacpac. I found a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502659/what-is-the-syntax-for-adding-multiple-arguments-onto-the-variables-parameter) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/87cd1fb1-9f63-4c60-a0af-56ade87a6f0d/specifing-sqlcmd-variable-values-when-using-sqlpackageexe?forum=ssdt).

But i am getting the following error:
**Missing values for the following SqlCmd variables:BuildVersion Description.
Description=$Description : The term 'Description=$Description' is not 
recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify 
that the path is correct and try again.**

Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

The correct switch for passing a SQLCMD variable to SQLPackage is like this
/v:Description=$Description

Powershell quoting is a bit tricky.
Here's an example for you:

https://gist.github.com/davoscollective/adf9b890984e51d8dee2

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe" ` #Note this is SQL Server 2012 specific directory, alter as needed
/Action:Publish `
/SourceFile:$sourceFile `
/TargetServerName:$targetServerName `
/TargetDatabaseName:$targetDBname `
/V:SQLCMDVariable1=$SQLCMDVariable1 ` #If your project includes other database references, or pre/post deployment scripts uses SQLCMD variables
/v:SQLCMDVariable2=$SQLCMDVariable2 `
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are using Powershell to call SqlPackage based on the cmdlet error. If this is the case ensure the Dollar symbols are escaped with a inverted apostrophe i.e.

> ie Description=**`**$Description

Could you post the full command you are passing?