# How to specify that .dacpac should use default SQLCMD variable values specified in VS2022 database project?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines, sqlcmd, visual-studio-2022

**I have an Azure SQL database project** which uses SQLCMD variables to set values dynamically. I am able to reference these variables as part of publish profiles that accompany the project and can even override them.

**I am using Visual Studio 2022 RC**.

**I also have an Azure DevOps pipeline** which checks out projects builds `.dacpac` and moves the `.dacpac` into the requisite directories prior to the deploy task that deploys the database into Azure.

The deploy task `SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1` is failing. The preceding build task is producing a `.dacpac` without the default SQLCMD variable values which are set at the project level.

> ##[error]*** An error occurred during deployment plan generation. Deployment cannot continue.

> ##[error]Missing values for the following SqlCmd variables:var1 var2.

> ##[error]The Azure SQL DACPAC task failed. SqlPackage.exe exited with code 1.Check out how to troubleshoot failures at https://aka.ms/sqlazuredeployreadme#troubleshooting-

To give some additional context, this is the part of the CI pipeline that is building and deploying.

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build projA database.'
  inputs:
    solution: 'projA\\projA.sqlproj'
    vsVersion: 16.0
    platform: 'x64'

- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  displayName: 'Deploy projA database.'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(ServiceConnectionName)'
    ServerName: '$(ServerName)'
    DatabaseName: '$(DatabaseName)'
    SqlUsername: '$(ServerUserName)'
    SqlPassword: '$(ServerUserPassword)'
    DacpacFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\\projA\\bin\\Output\\projA.dacpac'
```

I thought that the default values would be used when creating the `.dacpac`. This is not the case.

I tried also setting the `local` values to the same as `default` (these were previously blank) **but the same error arose**.

[image]

I have had a look a [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/sql-azure-dacpac-deployment?view=azure-devops) that indicates that additional variables can be supplied when deploying. I am not sure if I could apply values to existing variables using the `AdditionalArguments` clause in the deploy task.

Ideally I want the `.dacpac` to be produced with the SQLCMD default values supplied if not overridden, surely this should be the default behaviour. I wouldn't want to maintain values in multiple locations, this should be captured in the project.

I have read [How to use multiple SQLCMD variables with SqlPackage.exe while deploying a DacPac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29619570/how-to-use-multiple-sqlcmd-variables-with-sqlpackage-exe-while-deploying-a-dacpa) but this has not answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this I made use of the `publishProfile` argument **(last line in the code)** and referenced an existing publish profile which applied the default `SQLCMD` variable values to the target `.dacpac` during deployment via `sqlPackage.exe`.

```
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  displayName: 'Deploy projA database.'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(ServiceConnectionName)'
    ServerName: '$(ServerName)'
    DatabaseName: '$(DatabaseName)'
    SqlUsername: '$(ServerUserName)'
    SqlPassword: '$(ServerUserPassword)'
    DacpacFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\\projA\\bin\\Output\\projA.dacpac'
    publishProfile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\\projA\\projA.publish.xml'
```

I also had to switch from using Azure Active Directory Interactive authentication to SQL authentication because it isn't supported (because this is automation). I was using AADI Authentication in my publish profile.

I will use Azure Active Directory Integrated when moving this to a corporate VM which I authenticate to using that AAD account.

Another issue I faced was that the Azure SQL Database Instance blocks all IPs that are not on the green list, and I do not want to grant blanket access. I was using Microsoft Hosted agent which does not have a static IP. I installed an agent on my local machine, my public IP is green listed and so the deployment succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

The target platform of the SQL server on which you are attempting to deploy your dacpac differs from the target platform of the dacpac file.

Potential solutions:
[image]

Change the target platform in your dacpac project to the same platform as the SQL server's target platform.

Please try to add the values via `SqlCommandVariableValues`:

[image]

```
$options.SqlCommandVariableValues.Add("variable", $Variable)
```

You could even use PowerShell Script to add values as mentioned in this Steve Fenton’s Blog: [Here](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2016/02/pass-octopus-variables-to-dacpac-deployment-via-powershell/).

Comment: The target platform is already correctly set and I already set the SQLCMD variables. I am not writing a PS script to do this unless I have to and I am not directly calling SQLCMD. Your answer has caused me to re-read the argument documentation for `SqlAzureDacpacDeployment`. I think I know how to solve this using existing publish profiles which have the SQLCMD variables.